# Keeping variables in socket.io through multiple pages

Tags: node.js, session, express, socket.io

I am fairly new to node.js and socket.io, so some of these questions may seem really stupid. With that being said, I have been trying to develop an application which can store an username between different pages. For example, I set my username on one page. I then get redirected to another page, but my username still remains as a variable accessible in the socket connection.

Here is my basic server setup:

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);

app.get('/set', function(req, res){
    res.sendfile('set.html');
});

app.get('/get', function(req, res){
    res.sendfile('get.html');
});


io.on('connection', function(socket){



});


http.listen(3000, function(){
  console.log('listening on *:3000');
});
```

My questions are:

1.) It is possible to know what page the socket is currently on? If so, how?

2.) How can I interact with that information in the io.on(...)?

I have tried using session middleware for socket.io and express, but I can't seem to get any to work. I'm pretty sure that using sessions is the best method for this, but I don't know how to implement them. Any suggestions about setting up a sessions accessible through different pages would be nice as well.

Thanks you!

Comment: you should be able to check the referrer header  http://socket.io/docs/server-api/#socket#request:request

Answer (score 0):

You have to use express sessions and handshake for it:

```
    sock.on('your_socket_name', function (data) {
       sock.handhsake.session.name = data.name;
       sock.handshake.session.save();
    });
```

go through this link, it will sure help you:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/socket.io-handshake