# router.post() and 'Can't set headers after they are sent.' cause of 2x res.render - how to avoid this?

Tags: node.js, express

test.ejs

```
<form action="/test2" method="post"><input type="text" /><input type="submit" /></form>
```

test.js

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var router = express.Router();

    router.post('/test2', function(req, res) {
        res.render('test2'); // cause we need to render the page we send socket.io data to

        var socket_data = 'sd';
        req.io.in(room).emit('socket',{
            socket : socket_data
        }); // socket data is send

        var body = req.body.form_input; // our input value

        var someMoreCodeForExample = request('https:/www.google.com', function(err, resp, google){
            if (resp){
                res.render('test'); // can't render twice cause of first render is in the game... <-
            }
        }

        if (body == 'wrong'){
            var input_error = 'error';
            res.render('test', {errors : input_error}); // if input is wrong we redirect user to form page so he can use it again - can't render twice cause of first render is in the game... <-
        }
    }
```

So if user insert wrong input - he is redirected back to 'test' to submit correct input data. But... 'Can't set headers after they are sent.' how I can avoid this in this particular case (it's cause of 2x res.render but then how can I redirect user back to form?)?

Comment: Tests for equality in Javascript are with `==` or `===`, not `=`.

Comment: Correct - mistypo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change you're route to first test for `req.body` and then render based on its value:

```
router.post('/test2', function(req, res) {
    var body = req.body.form_input; // our input value

    if (body === 'wrong') {
        var input_error = 'error';
        res.render('test', {errors : input_error});
    } else {
        res.render('test2');
    }
})
```

The reason for your error is you're first rendering `test2` (i.e, sending a response) then testing for `req.body` value.

Comment: Correct, but I did simplify this example A LOT, I have edited my question feel free to look at it again.

Comment: @innertest You should probably re-think this specific route logic as you simply can't do anything after sending a response. That is, calling `render`, `redirect`, `end` or anything similar to that on the `res` object means you can't do anything further with it. You can probably try redirection at your frontend (AJAX callback ?) using `window.href.location`, but again, I suggest re-evaluating the situation and considering if this is the best way to work in this case. **TL;DR** you can not send a response after sending a response O_O

Comment: Thanks, well I can send data with socket but redirection (change of and url) is not possible anyway. And I still need to set socket connection at the beginning for timing... so data is send ASAP. Hmm but I guess I have no other choice then to defragment the application (with is hell of a job...).

Comment: BTW do know a way to NOT reconnecting socket every time url is changed - but keep the connection besides different page urls?

Comment: @innertest maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27665623/keeping-variables-in-socket-io-through-multiple-pages) question will help.

Comment: Thank you. I will play with handshake and see if it fit this project.